# Variável global não está sendo atribuida dentro de uma função AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Criei uma variavel global em JavaScript e estou fazendo uma requisição AJAX, dentro da função success do ajax, eu atribuo o retorno para a variavel global, porem ao sair do AJAX, a variavel fica indefinida.

```
var mesasPrint;

$.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL + 'mesas/get_mesas_ajax',
    success: function(result){
        mesasPrint = result;
        console.log(mesasPrint);
    }

});

console.log(mesasPrint);
```

O resultado é esse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A requisição ajax está funcionando, quando eu dou um `console.log` dentro da função success ele retorna o JSON, porem quando atribuo a variavel `mesasPrint` e tento usar fora da função, está como indefinida

Comment: Há um equívoco na sua interpretação. A variável global não fica indefinida ao sair do AJAX, ela está aparecendo como `undefined` no seu console porque você faz o log dela antes do AJAX terminar a requisição, e portanto, antes de atribuir um valor à `mesaPrint`.

Comment: O undefined está na linha 32, logo após a linha 27. Não sei porque no log aparece primeiro, mas se eu deixar apenas o console.log apos o ajax, continua undefined, porem o console log apenas dentro da requisição ajax, apresenta os dados

Comment: você precisa entender que a requisição ajax é assincrona, ou seja ela executa em segundo plano liberando o script a seguir e apenas depois que ela termina, ela executa a função success, ou seja, por mais rapido que a requisição seja concluida, a linha 27  sempre vai ser executada depois da linha 32. Coloque tudo o que você precisa fazer com a variavel mesasPrint dentro da função success do ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Não vou entrar a fundo, mas o que está acontecendo aqui é um asincronismo. Repare que no seu `AJAX` você declara uma função de callback na propriedade `success`. Por que você precisa declarar uma função ao invés de simplesmente continuar escrevendo o seu código normalmente? Porque essa função não é executada imediatamente, ela é um bloco de código que será executado quando seu AJAX terminar.

O seu código é executado nessa orderm:

```
// 1 - variável mesasPrint é inicializada
var mesasPrint;

// 2 - função AJAX é invocada
$.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL + 'mesas/get_mesas_ajax',
    success: function(result){
        // 4 - função de callback é executada eventualmente quando o AJAX finalizar
        mesasPrint = result;
        console.log(mesasPrint);
    }

});

// 3 - mesasPrint é printado no console
console.log(mesasPrint);
```

Isso ocorre para evitar que outras partes do código sejam bloqueados enquanto o código espera pela execução de uma operação de I/O demorada. O JavaScript não espera pelo AJAX, ou outras operações de I/O terminarem para continuar executando a próxima linha do código. Se o seu código precisa da resposta do AJAX para continuar, declare essa parte do código dentro da função de callback.

Você pode se aprofundar em outras maneiras de tratar o assincronismo com [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) e/ou [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)